# how to display a div triggered by onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have have two `div`s. I want to display a `div`( which has other `div`s inside it ) when the `onclick` event is triggered.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

[image: Mockup of a div containing a submit button and another div]

Comment: i have done display none to block by java script but its not working

Comment: jQuery: $('#your_button_id').click(function() { $('#your_div_id').show(); });

Comment: Welcome to the javascript community! I guess you have more than enough answers, anyway, here's a fixed/easy-to-understand/simpler/old-standard way to do this (in case you fail to fully comprehend/adapt derek's demo): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dM67/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go:

```
div{
    display: none;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("div").style.display = "block";
});

<div>blah blah blah</div>
<button>Show</button>
```

LIVE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/p78Qq/

Comment: Why does your code looks like jQuery translated to JS? Awesome. :P

Comment: When it comes from Derek, it's more like HTML6 or 7 :P

Answer (score 9):

You'll have to give an ID to the div you want to show/hide, then use this code:

html:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="tow">
        This is text
    </div>
    <button onclick="javascript:showDiv();">Click to show div</button>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function showDiv() {
    div = document.getElementById('tow');
    div.style.display = "block";
}
```

CSS:

```
​#tow { display: none; }​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkdNa/

Answer (score 4):

If you have the ID of the div, try this:

```
  <input type='submit' onclick='$("#div_id").show()'>
```

Comment: He never said he wanted jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function showstuff(boxid){
   document.getElementById(boxid).style.visibility="visible";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showstuff('id_to_show');" />
```

This will help you, I think.