# Click Button To Fill Listbox

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to fill a listbox on a webpage and I want the listbox to start blank.  Once the button is clicked the listbox should populate.  My code below automatically fills the listbox but I would rather have the button do it.

```
<?php 
$dbc = mysql_connect('','','') 
     or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.'); 

mysql_select_db('MyDB'); 

$result = mysql_query("select * from tblRestaurants order by RestName ASC"); 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 

<head> 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 

<title>SEARCH</title> 


 </head> 

<body> 
<form method="post" action="1004mcout.php">



<p><center>SEARCH</CENTER></P> 
<select name="RestName"> 
<?php 
 while ($nt= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
{ 
     echo '<option value="' . $nt['RestID'] . '">' . $nt['RestName'] . '</option>'; 
}  
?> 
</select>

<p> SPACE</p> 

<p>Click "SUBMIT" to display the calculation results</p> 

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 

<br /> 

</form> 

</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: I see you tagged this with AJAX, so you understand what technology is needed.  What have you tried thus far to implement your ajax calls? SO is not a "write my code for me" site.  We exepct that you have done some research, tried to do some implementation, etc. before posting a question.

Comment: I have done much research to get this far.  I am very new at this so a little help would be appreciated.  I know AJAX is the correct way to go, but how do I implement this with a button?  Is it an onClick event and then some.  I have an MS Access background.  So thats how I precieve things for now.  What are the terms that I need that mimic onClick?  Thank you.

Comment: Found this, but still fuzzy.    <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either: Preload the data into the page as some ready but invisible html list (maybe a bit n00b), or save the data as a javascript array and a function will load it into the page (better), or do an ajax call to the same page (for simplicity) (probably best, leaves you the option open for updated data after page initiation).

The Ajax route will have to use jQuery (change `this_page.php` to whichever page this is called):

```
<?php


while ($nt= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $arrData[] = $nt;

//If you want to test without DB, uncomment this, and comment previous
/*$arrData = array(
        array('RestID' => "1", 'RestName' => "Mike"),
        array('RestID' => "2", 'RestName' => "Sebastian"),
        array('RestID' => "3", 'RestName' => "Shitter")
        );*/

if(isset($_GET["ajax"]))
{
    echo json_encode($arrData);
    die();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function displayItems()
{
    $.getJSON("this_page.php?ajax=true", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, objRecord) {
            var option=document.createElement("option");
            option.value=objRecord.RestID;
            option.text=objRecord.RestName;
            $("#RestName").append('<option value="' + objRecord.RestID + '">' + objRecord.RestName + '</option>');
        });
    });

}
    </script>
    <title>SEARCH</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="1004mcout.php">
        <p><center>SEARCH</CENTER></P>
        <select id="RestName"></select>
        <p> SPACE</p> 
        <p>Click "SUBMIT" to display the calculation results</p> 
        <button type="button" onclick="javascript:displayItems();">Insert options</button>
        <br /> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Essentially, what it does, it collects the data, checks if there is a request for the ajax data in the url, if not, it prints the rest of the page (with an empty select). If there is an ajax flag in the url, then the php will encode the data into json, print that and stop.
When the User receives the page with an empty select, it clicks the button which will trigger the `displayItems()` function. Inside that function, it does a jQuery-based ajax call to the same page with the ajax flag set in the url, and the result (which is json), is evaluated to a valid javascript array. That array is then created into options and loaded into the RestName SELECT element.

A final cookie? You could just print the data as options, into the select anyway, just like the previous answers described. Then, inside the displayItems() function, you clear the select before loading it from the jQuery/ajax call. That way, the user will see data right from the beginning, and will only update this with the most recent data from the DB. Clean and all in one page.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This works!  I also have an understanding of how buttons and such work.  Once again thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. You probably noticed that I changed the name tag inside your SELECT to an id, to refer better to it with jQuery.
It might also be useful to lookup the many magical things that jQuery can do for you [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).
You also might find it useful to read about [3 reasons why you should let Google host jQuery for you](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/), hence my non-hosting of jQuery in this instance.

Comment: ...and if I can correct myself, I would, for aesthetic reasons, separate out any javascript from html. Instead of:

`function displayItems() { `

I would use:

`$("p").click(function() { `

(Don't forget to close properly as well: `});` ) And get rid of the ` onclick="javascript:displayItems();" ` inside the button.

Comment: Just wondering how difficult would it be to set this up with 5 buttons and one listbox.  Each button would run a different MySQL query.

Comment: I think you should then post a new question, this would produce bigger questions: Why would you want to reuse the same listbox for different mysql queries; How different are the mysql queries; Why not five different pages; etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$dbc = mysql_connect('','','') 
     or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.'); 

mysql_select_db('MyDB'); 

$result = mysql_query("select * from tblRestaurants order by RestName ASC"); 
?>

<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayResult()
{
   var x =document.getElementById("RestName");
   var option;

   <?php 
 while ($nt= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
 {
       echo 'option=document.createElement("option");' .
            'option.value=' . $nt['RestID'] . ';' . 
            'option.text=' . $nt['RestName'] . ';' .
            'x.add(option,null);';
 }  
  ?>
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <select name="RestName"> 
  </select>

  <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert options</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

[Read more about adding options to select element from java script here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp)

Comment: Thanl you.  I appreciate the answer as well as the link.  Being new to this its kinda like shooting in the dark.  Thank you for turning the light on!

Answer (score 1):

how about this simple way,
is this what you mean,

its not safe, any one can post show=yes but i think you just like users to be able to simply click and see result

```
<select name="RestName"> 
<?php 

// if show=yes
if ($_POST['show'] == "yes"){

$dbc = mysql_connect('','','') 
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.'); 

mysql_select_db('MyDB'); 

$result = mysql_query("select * from tblRestaurants order by RestName ASC"); 

 while ($nt= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
{ 
     echo '<option value="' . $nt['RestID'] . '">' . $nt['RestName'] . '</option>'; 
}
}
?> 
</select>

<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="hidden" name="show" value="yes" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

you can also simply use a hidden **div** to hid listbox and give the button an onclick action to show div, learn how in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10859950/1549838

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your input is so appreciated.  I've been searching days for this!